# React Native image shadow is not showing up on view

Tags: android, image, react-native

I have a png image with shadow in it.

[image]

But when I'm trying to add it in react native, the shadow is not coming up.

[image]

I've tried to give that view a shadow. I was able to add top shadow in IOS but Android doesn't support top shadow.

Is there any way to achieve top shadow in android or any way to show complete png file with shadow.

I am using React Native 0.55.4 and Android 8.0.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For android use  property `elevation: 1` or [react-native-shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow)
react-native-shadow working example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    ScrollView,
    Image,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'

import {BoxShadow} from 'react-native-shadow'

export default class VideoCell extends Component {
    render = () => {
        const shadowOpt = {
            width:160,
            height:170,
            color:"#000",
            border:2,
            radius:3,
            opacity:0.2,
            x:3,
            y:3,

            style:{marginVertical:5}
        }

        return (
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <BoxShadow setting={shadowOpt}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{
                  marginTop:10,
                    position:"relative",
                    width: 160,
                    height: 170,
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    borderRadius:3,
                    // marginVertical:5,
                    overflow:"hidden"}}>
                 <Text>Wnand</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </BoxShadow>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't give top shadow. Bottom shadow will come.

Comment: @Shubham check out my example. I have updated my answer

Comment: They are just adding an SVG below view. That don't feel like an actual shadow.

Comment: Any idea, why this shadow in the PNG is not showing up ?

Comment: You can try to increase elevation. The bigger elevation is a bigger shadow. Otherwise, in Android, there is no known solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the [react-native-shadow](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow) to create shadow views on Android.

The component will be something like:

```
const shadowOpt = {
    width:100,
    height:100,
    color:"#000",
    border:2,
    radius:3,
    opacity:0.2,
    x:0,
    y:3,
    style:{marginVertical:5}
}
<Shadow setting={shadowOpt}>
  ... your view here
</Shadow>
```